# What are some good smartphone emulators for web development on mac os x?

Tags: macos, testing, mobile-website

I am looking for some good smartphone emulators for web development on mac os x.

For iPhone we us iOS Simulator which works well, but we have been using Eclipse for Android emulation and it is bulky. We are mainly interested in Android, Nokia, Palm and blackberry. It would be great if there was a windows 7 mobile emulator, but I would doubt that.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't help you much with android, palm or blackberry default browsers as you will more than likely need to run windows on a mac to get them emulators however you have a few other options.

Nokia have an online emulator suite for signed up developer (free)
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/

Just checked and the nokia emulator doesn't have any windows phones

then a few browser emulators

http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/
http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/